# Стандартная генерация в Drupal

Tags: php, алгоритм, drupal

Подскажите, где в чистом Drupal происходит генерация *content type*-ов? По умолчанию на чистом Drupal уже можно добавлять *Article*, и меня интересует, где этот код генерации списка артиклов и открытого артикла.

Или какой модуль отвечает за эту генерацию?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За генерацию всего списка статей отвечает функция `node_page_default()` в файле node.module.

За отображение одной article (так же, как и отображение одной страницы другого типа) отвечает функция `node_page_view` из того же файла.